# Selecting multiple fields, returning what was not found

Tags: mongodb

I've made this query to return all email addresses that I am sending request for. Now the issue is, some of the accounts I am searching for don't have fields "email" therefore I wont get their email.

How do I make this so It tells me what query failed to find?

*(For example "Failed to find email for user with URI: Test#1"*

```
db.users.find({'uri_name':{$in:['#test1', '#test2', '#test3']}},{email:1, _id:0 });
```

Basically in this case #test1 and #test2 have field called "email" while "#test3" doesnt.

Comment: you can handle that in code easily, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following query to find the user who does not have the field email .

```
db.users.find( { email : { $exists: false } } )
```

You can execute the following query to find the user who has the email field as null or does not have the field email.

```
db.users.find( { email: null } )
```

To return both the users separately , (One has the email id and one does not has the email id) ,

try to use

> ifNull

Syntax:

> { $ifNull: [ expression, replacement-expression-if-null ] }

Usage: 
Try to do similar thing

> db.userbase.aggregate(    [
>
> ```
>   {
>
>      $user: {
>
>         item: 1,
>
>         email: { $ifNull: [ "$email", "Failed to find email for user with URI" ] }
>
>      }
>
>   }
> ```
>
> ] )

Comment: Hmmm yeah but how could I add up that to my query?

Comment: You can use db.users.aggregate...ie use ifNull . For Example : 

email: { $ifNull: [ "$email", "Failed to find email for user with URI:" ] } } } ] ) .

Comment: @TomislavNikolic : Have the answer helped you ?